# .#datepicker is not working is the error and icon is not clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

[image]

this the picture and the icon was not clicked even after the code that is below:

```
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker9'>
                                    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>                      
                    </div>

                            <script type="text/javascript">
                                $(function () {
                                    $('#datetimepicker10').datetimepicker({
                                        viewMode: 'years',
                                        format: 'MM/YYYY'
                                    });
                                });
                            </script>
```

Comment: please check your console is there any error

Answer (score 0):

**change your id datetimepicker9 to datetimepicker10**

```
 <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker10'>
                                    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>                      
                    </div>

                            <script type="text/javascript">
                                $(function () {
                                    $('#datetimepicker10').datetimepicker({
                                        viewMode: 'years',
                                        format: 'MM/YYYY'
                                    });
                                });
                            </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Change: datetimepicker10 to datetimepicker9
2. I guess you forgot to add jquery-ui (css + js).

   Make sure you run jquery-ui.js after you run jquery.js script

   `<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">`

   `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>`

   `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>`

You can see a working jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/alonshmiel/2vo60pzq/)